# Why SoftwarePackage don't have version?

Tags: autosar

In the `[SWS_UCM_00039]SwPackageInfoType` having property `Version` in the `SWS_UpdateAndConfigManagement`.
But there is no such property defined in the Manifest TPS.

BTW. For my understanding, the `struct` in SWS basically match the ARXML Manifest.
Because the data is read from it.
So as Manifest doesn't contains the SoftwarePakcage's version, where shall I get it?

And the most weird is `SwPackageInfoType` having `Name SwInfoName`, but the Description of `SwInfoName` is `SoftwareCluster name`...

Comment: There is a good chance that a fix for this issue will be included in the next release of AUTOSAR.

Comment: @UweHonekamp Looks like AUTOSAR don't have the community forum to report the issue...and the JIRA of AUTOSAR is not public...

Comment: If that's a problem for you: become a member with access to Jira.

Comment: SwPackage has a reference to the included `SwCluster` and `SwClusterDesign` have `version : StrongRevisionLabel
String`.

Comment: @kesselhaus There are many SoftwareCluster under SoftwarePackage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There only one SWCL in the software package.
So the version of SwPackageInfoType means the SWCL's version.
SoftwarePackage describes how SWCL shall be installed, and SWCL is part of it.

BTW In the comment of the question:

> There are many SoftwareCluster under SoftwarePackage

that is wrong.
SoftwareCluster have ROOT and SUB hierarchy, one SWCL may have many children. But for software package will not have the relationship.